# asp.net: How to manually (c#) select radiobutton in radiobuttonlist inside gridview from Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, radiobuttonlist

Im having problems after postback in asp.net / c#. All radiobuttlists in gridview are cleared on postback (one radiobuttonlist on each row). So I save them to a Session variable.

But I cant set them back from the Session variable. Here is the code in page_load:

```
//.. testing for null,etc
for (int i = 0; i < lstRadioButtons.Count; i++)
{
    RadioButtonList rbl = (RadioButtonList)gwTract.Rows[i].FindControl("RadioButtonList1");
    rbl.SelectedItem.Value = lstRadioButtons[i]; //list with strings "0", etc
    Debug.WriteLine("yep...");
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you binding your gridview with data?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `lstRadioButtons` contains the value for a given row:

```
for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < rbl.Items.Count; itemIndex++)
    if (rbl.Items[i].Value == lstRadioButtons[i])
        rbl.SelectedIndex = itemIndex;
```

Assuming `lstRadioButtons` contains the index for a given row:

```
rbl.SelectedIndex = int.Parse(i); //You may want to use TryParse to handle failure
```

Comment: Ah, it needs an if statement! Will try this!

Comment: Hm, didn't work.. Does radiobuttonlist need enableviewstate=true?